# basic python flask two page form input and update

Tags: python, forms, input, flask

I am a newbie to flask and trying to make form submission with two webpages.

Basically, there are two webpages, in the app.py they are routed as

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
...
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def results():
...
```

There are one form submission on '/' and one on '/results'. Right now, clicking the button on '/' redirects the user to '/results', with the input text sent to '/results' as well

```
<form method=post action='/results'>
    <dl>                                                       
    {{ render_field(form.channel_title ) }}                    
    </dl>                                                      
    <input type=submit value='analyze' name='sumbit_btn'>      
</form>
```

This part works. What I want to do now is to click the button on '/results' such that the text in its input form is used to update some text on itself. The problem is that in order to render '/results', input from '/' is needed.

```
def results():
    ....
    return render_template('results.html', channel=channel)
```

How can I implement this form submission on '/results' then, which send both its own form input and also the old input from '/' such that '/results' can be updated? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use an `<input type="hidden" value="your stuff"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the data to the flask session.

```
from flask import Flask, session, abort, request, render_template

@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    if request.form['channelname'] in ALLOWED_CHANNELS:
        session['channel'] = request.form['channelname']
    if 'channel' in session:
        return render_template('results.html', channel=session['channel'])
    else:
        abort(400)
```